# website is sending people to wrong address

Tags: redirect

I'm having trouble with my website.  I tried to log-in one day and I found myself being pointed to a completely different website/blog.

My dashboard link automatically redirects and I have no idea how to fix this.  Does anyone else have any clue how to get in touch with the right people or how to go about solving this?

Comment: How did you install WordPress? It sounds like your database has data from a previous install.

Comment: What is your URL?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a problem in your database. Did you import it from somewhere else? Specifically within your `wp_options` table, the `siteurl` option is incorrect.

Double check that to make sure it's the right site name. If it's wrong, then it's probably wrong in a lot of other areas too, but changing that key will at least allow you to login.

Comment: I did not.  It worked Wednesday, but when I tried to log-in Thursday my site was a church for cowboys.  I bookmarked my dashboard log-in, and even that redirects me to the log-in for this cowboy church's log-in.  I hadn't made changes to this site in weeks...

Comment: Did you check your database? That seems to be the most logical reason why your wp-admin is redirecting you to another website when you login. You can also verify it's wrong by going to your wp-admin, and hovering over the `"Back to <yoursite>"` link at the bottom. If it shows another website than your own, then the database definitely needs to be looked at.

Comment: Does the front-end go to the right place?

Comment: I can't check anything.  the log-in redirects me to someone else's log-in.  I can completely and totally cut off from my website/log-in

Comment: I should say that I'm not using any kind of upload database.  All my info and code was on the wordpress blog, that i no longer have access to.

Comment: Again - does the front-end go to the right place?